# Drosophila reference genome

Tags: genetics, genomes

Does anyone know the details about which line they are using to sequence as the *Drosophila melanogaster* reference genome?

Comment: Did you check the [genome publication](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10731132)

Comment: As far as I know they just used a generic _D. melanogaster_ lab strain.

Comment: does this help? http://www.fruitfly.org/annot/release3.html#strain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That *was* surprisingly buried.

I found this in a [paper describing genome build 3](http://genomebiology.com/2002/3/12/research/0079) - See "Materials and Methods".  I imagine that this is consistent through to the current build.  In any case it should get you started.

"Sequencing templates were made from P1, BAC and WGS DNA libraries using the D. melanogaster strain yellow (y1); cinnabar (cn1) brown (bw1) speck (sp1)."